# UWP Update UI From Async Worker

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, uwp, async-await

I am trying to implement a long-running background process, that periodically reports on its progress, to update the UI in a UWP app. How can I accomplish this? I have seen several helpful topics, but none have all of the pieces, and I have been unable to put them all together.

For example, consider a user who picks a very large file, and the app is reading in and/or operating on the data in the file. The user clicks a button, which populates a list stored on the page with data from the file the user picks.

**PART 1**

The page and button's click event handler look something like this:

```
public sealed partial class MyPage : Page
{
    public List<DataRecord> DataRecords { get; set; }

    private DateTime LastUpdate;

    public MyPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.DataRecords = new List<DataRecord>();
        this.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;

        // Subscribe to the event handler for updates.
        MyStorageWrapper.MyEvent += this.UpdateUI;
    }

    private async void LoadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StorageFile pickedFile = // … obtained from FileOpenPicker.

        if (pickedFile != null)
        {
            this.DataRecords = await MyStorageWrapper.GetDataAsync(pickedFile);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateUI(long lineCount)
    {
        // This time check prevents the UI from updating so frequently
        //    that it becomes unresponsive as a result.
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        if ((now - this.LastUpdate).Milliseconds > 3000)
        {
            // This updates a textblock to display the count, but could also
            //    update a progress bar or progress ring in here.
            this.MessageTextBlock.Text = "Count: " + lineCount;

            this.LastUpdate = now;
        }
    }
}
```

Inside of the `MyStorageWrapper` class:

```
public static class MyStorageWrapper
{
    public delegate void MyEventHandler(long lineCount);
    public static event MyEventHandler MyEvent;

    private static void RaiseMyEvent(long lineCount)
    {
        // Ensure that something is listening to the event.
        if (MyStorageWrapper.MyEvent!= null)
        {
            // Call the listening event handlers.
            MyStorageWrapper.MyEvent(lineCount);
        }
    }

    public static async Task<List<DataRecord>> GetDataAsync(StorageFile file)
    {
        List<DataRecord> recordsList = new List<DataRecord>();

        using (Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = reader.ReadLine();

                    // Does its parsing here, and constructs a single DataRecord …

                    recordsList.Add(dataRecord);

                    // Raises an event.
                    MyStorageWrapper.RaiseMyEvent(recordsList.Count);
                }
            }
        }

        return recordsList;
    }
}
```

The code for the time check I got from following [this](https://stephenhaunts.com/2014/10/14/using-async-and-await-to-update-the-ui-thread/).

As written, this code makes the app unresponsive with a large file (I tested on a text file on the order of about 8.5 million lines). I thought adding `async` and `await` to the `GetDataAsync()` call would prevent this? Does this not do its work on a thread aside from the UI thread? Through Debug mode in Visual Studio, I have verified the program is progressing as expected... it is just tying up the UI thread, making the app unresponsive (see [this page from Microsoft about the UI thread and asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/keep-the-ui-thread-responsive)).

**PART 2**

I have successfully implemented before an asynchronous, long-running process that runs on a separate thread AND still updates the UI periodically... but this solution does not allow for the return value - specifically the line from PART 1 that says:

```
this.DataRecords = await MyStorageWrapper.GetDataAsync(pickedFile);
```

My previous, successful implementation follows (most of the bodies cut out for brevity). Is there a way to adapt this to allow for return values?

In a `Page` class:

```
public sealed partial class MyPage : Page
{
    public Generator MyGenerator { get; set; }

    public MyPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.MyGenerator = new Generator();
    }

    private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.MyGenerator.ProgressUpdate += async (s, f) => await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, delegate ()
        {
            // Updates UI elements on the page from here.
        }

        this.MyGenerator.Start();
    }

    private void StopButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.MyGenerator.Stop();
    }
}
```

And in the `Generator` class:

```
public class Generator
{
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;

    public event EventHandler<GeneratorStatus> ProgressUpdate;

    public Generator()
    {
        this.cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Task task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while(true)
            {
                // Throw an Operation Cancelled exception if the task is cancelled.
                this.cancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                // Does stuff here.

                // Finally raise the event (assume that 'args' is the correct args and datatypes).
                this.ProgressUpdate.Raise(this, new GeneratorStatus(args));
            }
        }, this.cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this.cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Finally, there are two supporting classes for the `ProgressUpdate` event:

```
public class GeneratorStatus : EventArgs
{
    // This class can contain a handful of properties; only one shown.
    public int number { get; private set; }

    public GeneratorStatus(int n)
    {
        this.number = n;
    }
}

static class EventExtensions
{
    public static void Raise(this EventHandler<GeneratorStatus> theEvent, object sender, GeneratorStatus args)
    {
        theEvent?.Invoke(sender, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is key to understand that `async/await` does not directly say the awaited code will run on a different thread. When you do `await GetDataAsync(pickedFile);` the execution enters the `GetDataAsync` method still on the UI thread and continues there until `await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync()` is reached - and this is the **only** operation that will actually run asynchronously on a different thread (as `file.OpenStreamForReadAsync` is actually implemented this way).

However, once `OpenStreamForReadAsync` is completed (which will be really quick), `await` makes sure the execution returns to the same thread it started on - which means **UI thread**. So the actual expensive part of your code (reading the file in `while`) runs on UI thread.

You could marginally improve this by using `reader.ReadLineAsync`, but still, you will be returning to UI thread after each `await`.

### `ConfigureAwait(false)`

The first trick you want to introduce to resolve this problem is `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Calling this on an asynchronous call tells the runtime that the execution does not have to return to the thread that originally called the asynchronous method - hence this can avoid returning execution to the UI thread. Great place to put it in your case is `OpenStreamForReadAsync` and `ReadLineAsync` calls:

```
public static async Task<List<DataRecord>> GetDataAsync(StorageFile file)
{
    List<DataRecord> recordsList = new List<DataRecord>();

    using (Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = await reader.ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                // Does its parsing here, and constructs a single DataRecord …

                recordsList.Add(dataRecord);

                // Raises an event.
                MyStorageWrapper.RaiseMyEvent(recordsList.Count);
            }
        }
    }

    return recordsList;
}
```

### Dispatcher

Now you freed up your UI thread, but introduced yet another problem with the progress reporting. Because now `MyStorageWrapper.RaiseMyEvent(recordsList.Count)` runs on a different thread, you **cannot update the UI** in the `UpdateUI` method directly, as accessing UI elements from non-UI thread throws synchronization exception. Instead, you must use UI thread `Dispatcher` to make sure the code runs on the right thread.

In the constructor get reference to the UI thread `Dispatcher`:

```
private CoreDispatcher _dispatcher;

public MyPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    _dispatcher = Window.Current.Dispatcher;

    ...
}
```

Reason to do it ahead is that `Window.Current` is again accessible only from the UI thread, but the page constructor definitely runs there, so it is the ideal place to use.

Now rewrite `UpdateUI` as follows

```
private async void UpdateUI(long lineCount)
{
    await _dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
       // This time check prevents the UI from updating so frequently
       //    that it becomes unresponsive as a result.
       DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
       if ((now - this.LastUpdate).Milliseconds > 3000)
       {
           // This updates a textblock to display the count, but could also
           //    update a progress bar or progress ring in here.
           this.MessageTextBlock.Text = "Count: " + lineCount;

           this.LastUpdate = now;
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: I implemented this and it works perfectly! One minor edit, however: the datatype for `Window.Current.Dispatcher` was `CoreDispatcher`, not `Dispatcher` (perhaps this was a change with versions or something)

Comment: You are right my bad :-) . I wrote that part mostly from memory :-D . Glad it helped, happy coding!

Comment: Inside `UpdateUI` there is an `await`. Which means a thread is blocked until `RunAsync` is returned. This might introduce a deadlock. But there is no point doing that in this case.
There is a possibility to grab `SynchronizationContext.Current` in the constructor and use its `Post` method to implement *fire-and-forget*.
What I do not know is whether it is possible to combine `CoreDispatcher` and `Post`, though.